# LateInitializationError Chewie in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
LateInitializationError: Field '_latestValue@875205881' has not been initialized
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAXG1.png)

I do not know what is the cause of the problem I tried to put `?` Instead of `late` but there are still mistakes
Help me, thanks

video_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../screens/chewie_list_item.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoScreenState createState() => _VideoScreenState();
}

class _VideoScreenState extends State<VideoScreen> {
  ChewieController? _chewieController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ChewieListItem(
            videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.asset(
              'videos/video1.mp4',
            ),
            looping: true,
          ),
          ChewieListItem(
            videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.asset(
              'videos/video2.mp4',
            ),
            looping: true,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

chewie_list_item.dart

```
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class ChewieListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  // This will contain the URL/asset path which we want to play
  final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
  final bool looping;

  ChewieListItem({
    required this.videoPlayerController,
    required this.looping,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChewieListItemState createState() => _ChewieListItemState();
}

class _ChewieListItemState extends State<ChewieListItem> {
  late ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Wrapper on top of the videoPlayerController
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: widget.videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      // Prepare the video to be played and display the first frame
      autoInitialize: true,
      looping: widget.looping,
      // Errors can occur for example when trying to play a video
      // from a non-existent URL
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            errorMessage,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Chewie(
        controller: _chewieController,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    // IMPORTANT to dispose of all the used resources
    widget.videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
  }
}
```